# To play audio and image frames simultaneously in matlab

Tags: math, animation, image-processing, project

hello everyone 
i am doing a project in lip sync. 
however i am facing a problem here.  i have each frame of a picture which is generated from a sound unit.  now i would like to play the sound and the picture frames simultaneously so as to have an effect of a lip sync. i.e for a 2 second audio around 10 frames are generated.now how do i run this audio and picture frames together so as to obtain a 'lip sync' in matlab.
 thank u in advance

Answer (score 1):

hey  i found that out myself.The way to do is by using a TimerFcn with the required difference in the frame rate.the audio can be played by using 'audioplayer' and TimerFcn and TimerPeriod are the attributes of the audioplayer function.the TimerPeriod. for more help refer the link http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/audioplayer.html